# ios Swift Protocol Data

Tags: ios

I don't use storyboards.
I want to send protocol data using @objc button action.
However, the sent view controller does not run the protocol function.
May I know what the reason is?
In fact, there's a lot more code.
Others work, but only protocol functions are not executed.
The didUpdataChampion function is
Data imported into a different protocol.
I have confirmed that there is no problem with this.

```
protocol MyProtocolData {
    func protocolData(dataSent: String)
    func protocolCount(dataInt: Int)
}

class PickViewController: UIViewController,ChampionManagerDelegate{
 
    static let identifier = "PickViewController"
    
    var count = 0
    var urlArray = [URL]()
    
    var pickDelegate : MyProtocolData?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        champions.riot(url: "myURL")
     }
    @objc func topHand(){
        pickDelegate?.protocolData(dataSent: "top")
        print(count)
        pickDelegate?.protocoCount(dataInt: count)
        let cham = ChampViewController()
        cham.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(cham, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 //Data imported to another protocol
    func didUpdataChampion(_ championManager: ChampionManager, champion: [ChampionRiot]) {
        print(#function)
        count = champion.count
        for data in champion {
            let id = data.id
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.16.1/img/champion/\(id).png") else { return }
            urlArray.append(url)
            count = urlArray.count
        }

    }
    
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    
}
```

```
class ChampViewController: UIViewController,MyProtocolData {
    

    var pickData = ""
    var arrayCount = 0
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func protocolData(dataSent: String) {
        print(#function)
        pickData = dataSent
        print(pickData)
    }
    func protocoCount(dataInt: Int) {
        print(#function)
        arrayCount = dataInt
        print(arrayCount)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you set `pickDelegate` to `ChampViewController` object?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: you have `var pickDelegate : MyProtocolData?` variable, in order to make it work you need to set `ChampViewController` to this variable. I don't see this code

Comment: My code is that this is all. i'm@objc func topHand(){
pickDelegate?.protocolData(dataSent: "top")
pickDelegate?.protocoCount(dataInt: count)
With this part.
The protocol function within the ChampViewController is used to select
I just want to run it.
func protocolData(dataSent: String) {
print(#function)
pickData = dataSent
print(pickData)
}
func protocoCount(dataInt: Int) {
print(#function)
arrayCount = dataInt
print(arrayCount)
}

Comment: no, this is code where you're trying to pass value to your delegate. But this value is empty, because you haven't initialized it(default value is nil). You need to set this value to `ChampViewController` object, and how to do that is depends on your navigation

Comment: Do I have to do it this way?

Comment: protocol ChampionManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdataChampion(_ championManager :ChampionManager ,champion: [ChampionRiot])
    func didFailWithError(error : Error )
}

Comment: Check out [this article](https://learnappmaking.com/delegation-swift-how-to/) to understand how delegate works

Answer (score 0):

i don't see full code, for instance how you call bind to `topHand()`, my advice is:

1. check that `topHand` - is called
2. check that `pickDelegate` isn't nil inside `topHand`

Comment: pickDelegate 는 함수를 작동시키는 스위치 정도로만 알고있습니다. 혹시 nil인지 어떻게 확인할까요 ? print를 해보니 nil 로 확인되었습니다.

Answer (score 0):

Create Object fo your PickViewController class and set its delegate to self.

```
var yourObj = PickViewController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yourObj.delegate = self
    }
```